# How to open fancybox gallery with group photos via <a href=""> button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox

I have in array images that are grouped by id of the gallery and inside are images that belong to that gallery. i need somehow to append images to the same fancybox group and call this action via single unique `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` button.

Version: fancyBox v2.1.5

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $this->trans->btn['title']; ?></a>
```

This is the button i have several button in foreach loop that need to be unique.  fancybox css and js are already included in the html

```html
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $this->trans->btn['title']; ?></a>
```

Comment: which version of fancybox are you using?  If you use v3, you don't group with `rel` anymore - you group with `data-fancybox` - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage

Comment: Update the question: fancyBox v2.1.5

Comment: You need a proper href - fancybox 2 opens the href of the link - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fancybox v2 uses `data-fancybox-href`or `href` attribute as the source and `data-fancybox-group` or `rel` attribute as group name.